# Wordpress revolution slider grey box errors

Tags: slider, wordpress

Revolution slider is not working on my Wordpress site. it works with other themes but not the one currently running.

I was told the site is throwing out these two errors which are stopping it from working

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined s3Slider.js?ver=1:23
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'opera' of undefined custom.js?ver=1:16
```

But am unsure of how to resolve these or get the error to stop so the slider works

Site url: http://henrysstuff.co.uk/ - Slider is the grey element at the top

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You initialize the slider with the following code:

```
jQuery('#slider').s3Slider({
   timeOut: 3000
});
```

But there is no element with the id of "slider" found in your markup. This most likely is causing your first error.

The second error is because $.browser was removed in jQuery 1.9, and the site is running 1.9.1. Code below from custom.js line 16.

```
if (!jQuery.browser.opera) {
```

Comment: Thank you very much, getting rid of the jQuery problem seems to have resolved it. Thank you again